# Using IronPython on MS load tests

Tags: visual-studio-2012, python-3.x, resharper, mstest, ironpython

I am trying to use IronPython (2.7.3) in my MS load test (Visual studio 2012)

When calling : `var engine = Python.CreateEngine();`

I am getting :

> Failed to load language 'IronPython 2.7.3': The method or operation is not implemented. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.EqtStringPerThreadWriter.get_Encoding()
>      at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.get_Encoding()
>      at IronPython.Runtime.PythonFile.InitializeConsole(SharedIO io, ConsoleStreamType type, String name)
>      at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.SetStandardIO()
>      at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeSystemState()
>      at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext..ctor(ScriptDomainManager manager, IDictionary`2 options)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LanguageConfiguration.LoadLanguageContext(ScriptDomainManager domainManager, Boolean& alreadyLoaded)
>      at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DlrConfiguration.LoadLanguageContext(ScriptDomainManager manager, LanguageConfiguration config)
>      at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DlrConfiguration.TryLoadLanguage(ScriptDomainManager manager, AssemblyQualifiedTypeName providerName, LanguageContext& language)
>      at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.ScriptDomainManager.GetLanguageByTypeName(String providerAssemblyQualifiedTypeName)
>      at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptRuntime.GetEngineByTypeName(String assemblyQualifiedTypeName)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
>      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
>      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance(String typeName)

It's strange because when I am running a single unit test everything works perfectly.

I have IronPython 2.7.3 installed and have all the IronPython requested DLLs in my project.

In addition, I am also using Resharper for tests executing - When I ran a single test it's works and when i am trying to run a set of tests together it's crashes with same exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve it :

```
var runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup);
var ms = new MemoryStream();
runtime.IO.SetOutput(ms, new StreamWriter(ms));
runtime.IO.SetErrorOutput(ms, new StreamWriter(ms));
var engine = runtime.GetEngine("IronPython");
```

Apparently , i need to add the output streams.